# What's the required voltage for ws2815?

Tags: led, esp8266

I am working on ws2815 led strip with the esp8266 on **arduino 1.6.6** [fast led](http://fastled.io/) library.Using CD40109B level shifter to convert 3.3V of esp output to 12V .It's working fine upto 31 leds according to the program pattern if i increase the led count it's giving random pattern .What can be the issue.
This is the code that i am using

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define LED_PIN     5
#define NUM_LEDS    50

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2813, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i <=NUM_LEDS ; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB (255,0 , 0);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(40);
  }
  for (int i = NUM_LEDS; i >= 0; i--) {
    leds[i] = CRGB ( 0, 255, 0);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(40);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
We checked in oscilloscope and we observed that after internal signal reshaping of the ws2815 IC ,the RGB values are not as intended.This is also seen on the led strip with changing colour of the leds.
We are trying to generate a single colour on the strip so this colour changing is quite clear.

---

The current rating of the power supply I am using is 12.5A, which is enough to drive the LEDs, and the voltage is also 12V at the 32nd LED.

Comment: The voltage levels needed for the WS2815: see the datasheet. Your question is inconsistent. You ask about voltages in the subject but in the text you mention averything is fine up to 31 LEDs. So what makes you think the voltages are not OK? The LEDs work so the voltages must be OK. How about there being something unexpected happening in the program?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie That's what i am confused .previously i was worked on ws2812, after using level shifter it worked fine but not sure what is causing the problem to this one.

Comment: Well then it's not the voltage, is it? Note that 31=2^5-1 and 32=2^5. My hunch is there is some part of your code that is hard-coded for less than 2^5 bits or uses a 5-bit field for some important value.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson but it worked fine for ws2812b led strip.Same principle for ws2812 and ws2815 only difference is data pin voltage which is 5V for ws2812 and 12V ws2815.

Comment: If this code worked for other kinds of LEDs, you were just lucky. You've committed the common error of writing beyond the end of your array, in both of your `for()` loops. The last location in `leds[]` is `NUM_LEDS-1`, not `NUM_LEDS`. It sounds like you finally got unlucky and started clobbering something important. It isn't too surprising that this occurs at a power-of-2 boundary.

Comment: @Dave Tweed sorry i used NUM_LEDS-1 only while copying i did mistake.

Comment: Well, the code in your question still shows the error. How did a simple copy-paste operation create an error like that anyway? If this isn't an exact copy of the code you're actually running, how are we to know whether there are any other differences?

Comment: You say you are level-shifting the data from 3.3V to 12V, but the datasheet for the WS2815B indicates the maximum rating for the logic input (the DI pin) is 5.3V. It is only the supply voltage that is 12V.

Comment: Another issue that I have noticed is that the code works fine with the brightness level upto 150 and the programmed pattern is observed on the led strip. However, if I increased the brightness level to 255, the code fails after a certain length. What could be the issue?

Comment: Same issue here, actually, after the 400th led maybe. My goal is to drive 639 leds.
I tried with both arduino nano and stm32, but, nothing worked. Please, tell me if you got a solution.
Regrds,
Tommy